# Measuring impact of gpu acceleration on rendering time of websites

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, graphics-card, performance, gpu

How can I measure what, if any, speed up website loading times during webbrowsing with Firefox (or Chrome) an added dedicated graphic card (Nvidia GT 1030) provides over an old integrated one (Radeon HD 3000)?

I have checked common synthetic benchmark like Basemark, webxprt2015 or Motionmark, but I am looking for a more natural way with websites I actually use.
I am aware of the possibility of checking load times in the network console, but I was wondering if there are faster and better automatable ways of doing this with a list of websites, if possible without extensive scripting (e.g. IMacros).